# Spring Integration - Scatter-Gather

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration and Scatter Gather handler (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M1/reference/html/scatter-gather.html) in order to send 3 parallel requests (using ExecutorChannels) to external REST APIs and aggregate their response into one single message.

Everything works fine until exception is thrown within Aggregator's aggregatePayloads method (AggregatingMessageHandler). In this scenario error message is successfully delivered to Messaging Gateway which initiated the flow ( caller ). However, ScatterGatherHandler thread remains in hanging state waiting for gatherer reply (I believe) which never arrives due to the exception within it. I.e each sequential call leaves one additional thread in "stuck" state and eventually Thread Pool runs out of available working threads.

My current Scatter Gather configuration:

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler distributor() {
    RecipientListRouter router = new RecipientListRouter();
    router.setChannels(Arrays.asList(Channel1(asyncExecutor()),Channel2(asyncExecutor()),Channel3(asyncExecutor())));
    return router;
}

@Bean
public MessageHandler gatherer() {
    AggregatingMessageHandler aggregatingMessageHandler = new AggregatingMessageHandler(
            new TransactionAggregator(),
            new SimpleMessageStore(),
            new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy("correlationID"),
            new ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy("size() == 3"));
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion( true );
    return aggregatingMessageHandler;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "validationOutputChannel")
public MessageHandler scatterGatherDistribution() {
    ScatterGatherHandler handler = new ScatterGatherHandler(distributor(), gatherer());
    handler.setErrorChannelName("scatterGatherErrorChannel");

    return handler;
}


@Bean("taskExecutor")
@Primary
public TaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

So far the only solution that I found is to add RequiresReply and GatherTimeout values for ScatterGatherHandler like below:

```
handler.setGatherTimeout(120000L);
handler.setRequiresReply(true);
```

This will produce an exception and release ScatterGatherHandler's thread to the pull after specified timeout value and after aggregator's exception is delivered to the messaging gateway. I can see following message in the log:

```
[AsyncThread-1] [WARN] [o.s.m.c.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel:] [{}] - Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply: ErrorMessage
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? My main goal is to make sure that I am not blocking any threads in case of exception is thrown within aggregator's aggregatePayloads method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is really an expect behavior. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#scatter-gather-error-handling

> In this case a reasonable, finite `gatherTimeout` must be configured for the `ScatterGatherHandler`. Otherwise it is going to be blocked waiting for a reply from the gatherer forever, by default.

There is really no way to break expectations from the `BlockingQueue.take()` from that `ScatterGatherHandler` code.

Comment: thank you, Artem, for confirmation. I will follow this approach in my code.